# why EC2 /etc/resolv.conf is always got empty, and rebooting the instance can fill the values, but later on it will be empty again

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, resolv

Does anyone know the reason why the `/etc/resolv.conf` is got empty at sometimes and rebooting the instance, it can fill correct values into it, but after a while, it will be empty again, all the instances created by the same AMI have this issue.

the instances are under a `VPC`, and we have enabled `DNS resolution` and `DNS hostnames`, and even `ClassicLink DNS Support`.

and running `dhcpclient` doesn't work.

Can someone help? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It turns out to be the full disk issue, I have run out of disk space, so the dhcpclient cannot write content to the resolve.conf file, and if I reboot the instance then it got a little disk space, and dns resolution works fine, but after a while, it stops working because of no disk space.

Thanks.